# Запрос выполняется в Access, но не работает при выполненении его из кода c#

Tags: c#, sql, access

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: построил запрос в MS Access, он выполняется, вот скрин при нажатии на "выполнить":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при показе SQL кода, копирую код и вставляю в c#, запускаю выполнение.... и получаю 0 обновленных записей. Сам код:

```
INSERT INTO coins ( coin_name, symbol, url_on_coinmarketcap )
SELECT coins_info.coin_name, coins_info.symbol, coins_info.url_loaded
FROM coins_info
WHERE (((coins_info.coin_name) Is Not Null) AND ((coins_info.symbol) Not In (SELECT symbol FROM coins WHERE coins_info.coin_name = coins.coin_name OR coins_info.symbol = coins.symbol)) AND ((coins_info.url_loaded) Like "*coinmarketcap*"));
```

Почему он работает в Access, но не работает если выполнять запрос SQL к БД? Как его выполнить из кода c#?

```
int count_added = ZennoPoster.Db.ExecuteNonQuery(
    "INSERT INTO coins ( coin_name, symbol, url_on_coinmarketcap ) SELECT coins_info.coin_name, coins_info.symbol, coins_info.url_loaded FROM coins_info WHERE (((coins_info.coin_name) Is Not Null) AND ((coins_info.symbol) Not In (SELECT symbol FROM coins WHERE coins_info.coin_name = coins.coin_name OR coins_info.symbol = coins.symbol)) AND ((coins_info.url_loaded) Like '*coinmarketcap*'));",
    null,
    ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.Enums.Db.DbProvider.OleDb,
    project.Variables["connection_string"].Value);

return count_added;
```

Comment: Покажите свой код C#.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov int count_added = ZennoPoster.Db.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO coins ( coin_name, symbol, url_on_coinmarketcap ) SELECT coins_info.coin_name, coins_info.symbol, coins_info.url_loaded FROM coins_info WHERE (((coins_info.coin_name) Is Not Null) AND ((coins_info.symbol) Not In (SELECT symbol FROM coins WHERE coins_info.coin_name = coins.coin_name OR coins_info.symbol = coins.symbol)) AND ((coins_info.url_loaded) Like '*coinmarketcap*'));", null, ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.Enums.Db.DbProvider.OleDb, project.Variables["connection_string"].Value);

return count_added;

Comment: Like 'coinmarketcap' через * естественно написан, здесь автозамена убирает и делает курсивом. Все везде нормально, все остальные запросы работают, которых больше сотни на всю программу, так что в connection_string или где-либо еще ошибки быть не может, структура скопирована с другого, рабочего запроса. Заменен только код запроса. Что-то видимо Access интерпретирует перед выполнением, чего не происходит при прямом SQL запросе, но не пойму что именно. Если убрать из запроса все что связано с url - запрос работает отлично и через SQL, но мне нужно добавлять и это поле, а не только name и symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Сам наткнулся на эти "грабли". Решил так:

В `LIKE` запроса заменил `*` на `%`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]